# If a particular constant contains every single possible combination of numbers in it's decimal expansion, does it also contain itself?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

If a particular constant $a$ contains every single combination of numbers in it's decimal expansion, does it then imply that at one point the series should also contain itself?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  surely the premise is "every finite string of digits occurs somewhere in the decimal expansion of $a$", no?  But that doesn't mean that every infinite string occurs (you can't have infinitely many consecutive $2's$ and infinitely many consecutive $1's$ occurring, for example.

Comment: @lulu, you could have 0.12112211122211112222...

Comment: @Michael  Those aren't consecutive.  The "finite string" premise is clearly possible (as in the Champernowne number, $.012345678910111213...$).  But if, say, the infinite string $111\dots $ occurred then there could only be finitely many strings before it....

Comment: It shows that 'every finite string' does not force 'every infinite string' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose it contains itself, starting at the $n+1$th significant digit.
Then it also contains itself starting at the $2n+1$th significant digit.  The second occurrence has the third occurrence, in the same place the first occurrence has the second occurrence - delayed by $n$ digits.
So it repeats every $n$ digits.  So it contains only $n$ different $n$-digit numbers, which is a contradiction.